# HOw can i ensure that Page Layout wont damage if tag is missing?

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm giving the ability to insert html as text via textbox multiline which then inserted to literal

```
//-----Page-----------
//--------------------
//-------------------
//--| Literal |-----
//-------------------
//--------------------
```

I don't want to use html editor

the text of the textbox which is html tags is inserted in the middle of the page to a specific literal.

but sometimes they forget to end Tags.  like `</xxx>`

so the whole page is messed up

i tried to wrap all the content with div but no success.

how can i reslove it that even when the html (inner html) is not completed - the whole page wont messed up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here just asks for Cross Site Scripting attack.

I don't understand why you don't want to use HTML editor to edit HTML.

You would have to parse the string on the server and fix any problems. I would recommend using [**HtmlAgilityPack**](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing malformed html.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [StackOverflow tag balancer](http://refactormycode.com/codes/360-balance-html-tags).

It will look for unmatched tags and automatically remove them.

Comment: Wow, neat!  Forget what I said - this is a much better option!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the validity of the HTML during the user editing phase?

Once the user tries to save, treat their text as HTML and validate its DOM.  If it's not valid, don't let them save without fixing it.

On one hand, the next thing they're going to ask you is to tell them what's not valid about it, but if they need to hand-code HTML instead of using an HTML editor to do it for them, I guess they should be smart enough to figure out what's not valid in what they added.  ;)